# Error when redirecting with Twitter oauth

Tags: python, flask, twython

I'm new to Flask and I'm trying to do do oauth with Twitter using Twython. Following is my code (development version):

```
OAUTH_TOKEN = ''
OAUTH_TOKEN_SECRET = ''
callback_url = 'http://127.0.0.1:5000/verify'
@app.route('/')
def hello(name=None):
    return render_template('index.html', name=name)

@app.route('/auth', methods=['POST'])
@cross_origin()
def obtain_auth_url():
    global OAUTH_TOKEN, OAUTH_TOKEN_SECRET
    social_network = request.get_json()['social_network']
    if social_network == 'facebook':
        return ''
    elif social_network == 'twitter':
        twitter = Twython(APP_KEY, APP_SECRET)
        auth = twitter.get_authentication_tokens(callback_url)
        OAUTH_TOKEN = auth['oauth_token']
        OAUTH_TOKEN_SECRET = auth['oauth_token_secret']
        redirect_url= auth['auth_url']
        response = redirect(redirect_url)
        response.headers = {'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': 'https://api.twitter.com/'}  
        print('redirect_url: ',redirect_url)
        return response

@app.route("/verify")
def get_verification():
    global OAUTH_TOKEN
    global OAUTH_TOKEN_SECRET
    twitter = Twython(APP_KEY, APP_SECRET,OAUTH_TOKEN, OAUTH_TOKEN_SECRET)
    final_step = twitter.get_authorized_tokens(request.args['oauth_verifier'])
    OAUTH_TOKEN2 = final_step['oauth_token']
    OAUTH_TOKEN_SECRET2 = final_step['oauth_token_secret']
    return 'OK!</br> OAUTH TOKEN:' + OAUTH_TOKEN2 +'</br> OAUTH TOKEN SECRET: '+ OAUTH_TOKEN_SECRET2
```

Note that in the code, I add the header `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` to enable the redirect to twitter api domain. If I don't include the header, it throws a cross origin block error. 
However, on the browser (Firefox), is said:

> XML Parsing Error: syntax error Location: http://127.0.0.1:5000/auth
>   Line Number 1, Column 55:

Clearly, the endpoint `/auth` has been reached because I can see the redirect url via log, but I don't understand why I have the error.
Please help.